# How to pass JSON values

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, highcharts, asp.net-mvc-5

Hola people back over here, I have a doubt as to pass JSON to these two variable in order to create my chart dynamically.
That's how I pass the values:
**The fields to be completed are: Categories and Data**

```
Public ActionResult Index()
    {
        DotNet.Highcharts.Highcharts chart = new DotNet.Highcharts.Highcharts("chart")
            .SetXAxis(new XAxis
            {
                Categories = new[] { "Jan", "Feb" }
            })
            .SetSeries(new Series
            {
                Data = new Data(new object[] { 29.9, 71.5})
            });

        return View(chart);
    }
```

My idea is this more or less to create the JSON:

```
public JsonResult GetPedidoLocalidad()
    {
        var data = GetDatosLoc();
        return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        //return data;
    }
    private List<EstadisticaViewModels> GetDatosLoc()
    {
        var allData = (from p in db.Pedidos.Include("Localidad")
                      group p by p.Localidad.Nombre into pedGrupo
                      select new EstadisticaViewModels()
                      {
                          Nombre = pedGrupo.Key,
                          Cantidad = pedGrupo.Count()
                      });
        var OrderData = allData.ToList();
        return OrderData;
    }
```

**I am using this example:**
[DotNetHighcharts](https://dotnethighcharts.codeplex.com/)

Comment: ... and whats actually your question? How to fill them? How to convert from JSON to array?

Comment: where will the JSON come from? Database, ajax request from the browser, something else?

Comment: I just edit the question, basically what I need to know how to create a method that and return on the one hand the category (Labels) and other data (values) in these variables must receive the JSON to create the graph, it is understood ?
The data comes from database, I want to load into JSON and pasaros these two variables.

Comment: i think, you are trying for two variable return in single JSON?

Comment: In principle if though I think it would be logical to do so individually, that's not why I consult them how to implement.

Comment: @Max ok i see. why do you want JSON then? Your chart seems to be configured on the server-side. You would only need JSON if you want to configure the charts using Javascript instead. Do you want to set up the chart using client-side (javascript) code instead? If not, then JSON is not relevant here - you would just retrieve your data from the database and put it into the arrays as variables instead of static values.

Comment: @ADyson - Excellent answer, now also achieves understand the difference. Good basis of understanding, the graphics would create server-side (without JSON), as you say, passing the values as arrays.

Comment: Any help please? Thank you

Comment: @Max Since you do not want JSON any more I suggest updating the questions, because right now it's not clear what is the problem here.

Comment: if I want to generate a JSON, which is not how to format, that is the question.